# InverseLaplaceTransform provides a wrong answer?

Tags: integral-transforms

**Question is revised as below:**

I'm trying to define a function involving inverse of a Laplace Transform for a rational function, but *Mathematica* provides a wrong result. Can anyone help on this?

Here's the code:

```
beta1 = 1/15; beta2 = 1/10; w1 = 0.4;lambda=0.15;

f[y_, t_] := Exp[-lambda* t]*(Sum[(lambda* t)^n/(n!)*InverseLaplaceTransform[(w1*beta1/(beta1 + s) + (1 - w1)* beta2/(beta2 + s))^n, s, y], {n, 1, 20}]);

f[20,13] (*try to test the result*)
```

*Mathematica* 10 provides an answer of -0.0547458, which is incorrect as the value should be positive.

This function will be used in integration later on, which means that it will be called repeatedly.  Why this is wrong here. Are there any other ways to define it?

Comment: This is a question about InverseLaplaceTransform, but adding such a tag requires 300 reputations...

Comment: `With[{beta1 = 1/15, beta2 = 1/10, w1 = 2/5, n = 13, ya = 500}, InverseLaplaceTransform[(w1*beta1/(beta1 + s) + (1 - w1)*beta2/(beta2 + s))^n, s, y] /. y -> ya] // N` gives your expected result.

Comment: @J. M. Thank you very much for your reply! It works now, so I guess the issue comes from the unspecified n? The reason I code using a function is that I will need to add n from 1 to N (for a large N). Now I simply sum "n" without defining yn[y_,n_] and the result is correct.

Comment: @J.M.  Would you please help on the question further? Eventually I need: f[y_, t_] := 
  Exp[-lambda*
     t]*(Sum[(lambda*t)^n/(n!)*
      InverseLaplaceTransform[(w1*beta1/(beta1 + s) + (1 - w1)*
           beta2/(beta2 + s))^n, s, y], {n, 1, 20}]);              It will be used for integration later on; For small values, it works. But I found that for larger t, it still provide inaccurate value. e.g. f[20,13] shows a negative value. Is there an alternative way to define the function?, Ideally, I could get an symbolic inversed expression, since it will be repeatedly called during integration.

Comment: If you want to extend your question please [edit] the question itself. add **there** any extra questions, data or context.

Comment: @rhermans, Thanks for your remind. I revised the question to make it clearer.